# How to use showexpl with an external class?

Tags: listings, document-classes, examples, showexpl

The `showexpl` package defines `LTXexample` environment which allows to define a latex code and shows its result side by side. The problem is that it uses the same document class where the LaTeX code is defined and I would like to define which class to use for examples. Do you know if it's possible?

Here you have an examples. It's a `beamer` presentation with some `LTXexample`s.

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{showexpl} 
\lstloadlanguages{[LaTeX]Tex} 
\lstset{% 
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small, 
    commentstyle=\itshape\ttfamily\small, 
    showspaces=false, 
    showstringspaces=false, 
    breaklines=true, 
    breakautoindent=true, 
    captionpos=t 
} 

\begin{document} 
\frame[containsverbatim]{ 
  \frametitle{First slide} 
  \begin{LTXexample} 
    \begin{itemize} 
       \item a 
       \item b 
       \item c 
    \end{itemize} 
  \end{LTXexample} 

  \begin{LTXexample} 
    \begin{equation} 
       a^2+b^2=\sqrt{\frac{c^2}{1}} 
    \end{equation} 
  \end{LTXexample} 
} 

\frame[containsverbatim]{ 
  \frametitle{Second slide} 
  \begin{LTXexample} 
     \documentclass{article} 
     \begin{document} 
     \section{Section 1} 
        Text for section 1 
     \end{document} 
  \end{LTXexample} 
} 
\end{document}
```

Second slide doesn't show 'section title' because beamer has its own 
section behaviour, so it seems that `\documentclass{article}` inside the 
example doesn't have any effect. The resulting font is sanserif 
because beamer uses it.

I know I can use several external documents and insert code and results, but with `LTXexample` or a similar environment would be easier. Do you know a better solution?

Addendum: This problem has been solved with `tcolorbox` instead of `sowexpl` by [Thomas F. Sturm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222498/1952) in [Article example inside beamer frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222475/article-example-inside-beamer-frame/222498#222498)

Comment: +1 for introducing me to showexpl, I spent hours this week more or less doing this by hand... Sigh.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The code must be compiled externally. Loading the code of article.cls and all sorts of packages in the beamer run would lead to chaos. But theoretically if --shell-escape is active it is possible to trigger this external run on-the-fly during the compilation of the beamer run and then to include the resulting pdf with the graphic-option of showexpl. The main problem I see is that you probably don't want to include a complete page but only a part of it (e.g. to show the section). I think it would be difficult to write a good and flexible interface to choose this part.

Comment: The LaTeX team had to do something like this for _The LaTeX Companion_, as a lot of the example packages cannot be mixed. I believe the way it was done was using some special markers in the example `.tex` files ('start included preamble', 'start included body', _etc._), plus a Makefile set up. There is some detail toward the end of the book.

Comment: @JosephWright I know this question is three years old, but could you elaborate on your comment, perhaps post your own answer, please? I find Ulrike's answer a bit too handwavy and I'm not sure what to do...

Comment: @Jubobs: You can find some information about the process mentioned by Joseph in CTAN. All LC2 examples and classes used to make them are [there](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/examples/lgc2).

Answer (score 9):

This is not a 'fully worked up' solution for all cases, but I hope is enough of an answer to show how things can be done in a reasonably flexible way. The code in `showexpl` is pretty long, and so breaking into it to add the ability to use an external compilation is a bit tricky. Instead, I'm using some code I've adapted from the `listings` sources in my own packages, and adding an additional ability to that. As a result, you don't get all of the bells and whistles of `showexpl` out of the box, although you could add them:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ifplatform}
\usepackage{listings}
\makeatletter
\lst@RequireAspects{writefile}
\newbox\LaTeXdemo@box
\newbox\LaTeXdemo@graphics
\lstnewenvironment{LaTeXdemo}[1][code-and-example]{%
  \global\let\lst@intname\@empty
  \ifcsname LaTeXdemo@#1@end\endcsname
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\LaTeXdemo@end
      \csname LaTeXdemo@#1@end\endcsname
    \csname LaTeXdemo@#1\expandafter\endcsname
  \else
    \ERROR
  \fi
}{%
  \LaTeXdemo@end
}
\newcommand*{\LaTeXdemo@common}{%
  \setkeys{lst}{%
    basewidth    = 0.51 em,
    basicstyle   = \small\ttfamily ,
    gobble       = 2,
    keywordstyle = \color{blue},
    language     = [LaTeX]{TeX},
    moretexcs    =
      {
        % Add list of additions here, e.g.
        email
      }
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\LaTeXdemo@input}{%
  \catcode`\^^M=10\relax
  \small
  \begingroup
    \leavevmode
    \input{\jobname.tmp}%
  \endgroup
}

\@namedef{LaTeXdemo@code-and-example}{%
  \setbox\LaTeXdemo@box=\hbox\bgroup
    \lst@BeginAlsoWriteFile{\jobname.tmp}%
    \LaTeXdemo@common
}
\@namedef{LaTeXdemo@code-and-example@end}{%
    \lst@EndWriteFile
  \egroup
  \begin{center}
    \ifdim\wd\LaTeXdemo@box>0.48\linewidth\relax
      \hbox to\linewidth{\box\LaTeXdemo@box\hss}%
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
          \LaTeXdemo@input
        \end{minipage}
    \else
      \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
        \LaTeXdemo@input
      \end{minipage}
      \hfill
      \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
        \hbox to\linewidth{\box\LaTeXdemo@box\hss}%
      \end{minipage}
    \fi
  \end{center}
}

\expandafter\let\csname LaTeXdemo@code-and-external\expandafter\endcsname
  \csname LaTeXdemo@code-and-example\endcsname
\@namedef{LaTeXdemo@code-and-external@end}{%
    \lst@EndWriteFile
  \egroup
  \immediate\write18{pdflatex -jobname \jobname-demo 
    "\unexpanded\expandafter{\LaTeXdemo@documentclass@move}
     \noexpand\input \jobname.tmp"}%
  \begin{center}
    \ifdim\wd\LaTeXdemo@box>0.48\linewidth\relax
      \hbox to\linewidth{\box\LaTeXdemo@box\hss}%
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
          \includegraphics{\jobname-demo}%
        \end{minipage}
    \else
      \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
        \includegraphics{\jobname-demo}%
      \end{minipage}
      \hfill
      \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
        \hbox to\linewidth{\box\LaTeXdemo@box\hss}%
      \end{minipage}
    \fi
  \end{center}
  \immediate\write18{\ifwindows del\else rm\fi \jobname-demo.pdf}%
}
\begingroup
  \catcode`\#=12 %
  \gdef\LaTeXdemo@documentclass@move{%
    \let\LaTeXdemodocumentclass\documentclass
    \renewcommand{\documentclass}[2][]{%
      \let\documentclass\LaTeXdemodocumentclass
      \begingroup
      \edef\x{%
        \endgroup
        \noexpand\documentclass[class=#2,varwidth,#1]{standalone}%
      }%
      \x
    }%
  }
\endgroup
\makeatother

\begin{document} 
\begin{frame}[fragile] 
\frametitle{An example in the beamer class} 
\begin{LaTeXdemo} 
  \section{foobar}
  \begin{itemize} 
    \item foo 
    \item bar
  \end{itemize} 
\end{LaTeXdemo} 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[fragile] 
\frametitle{An example in the article class} 
\begin{LaTeXdemo}[code-and-external]
  \documentclass{article}
  \begin{document}
  \section{foobar}
  \begin{itemize} 
    \item foo 
    \item bar
  \end{itemize} 
  \end{document}
\end{LaTeXdemo} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The idea in the above is to provide different ways of printing examples: I've included only 'code plus demo' and 'code plus externally-compiled demo', but 'code only' and 'code plus floating demo' are easy enough to do: I can add in if there is interest. (I guess also 'code plus floating externally-compiled demo', if really wanted!) As it stands, the code assumes the aim is a 'side by side' presentation but does no scaling if that won't fit, instead placing the output below the code. That can easily be adjusted, but perhaps would be best as a separate (linked) question.

The tricky part is getting a 'tight' page around the output using an external compilation (assuming that is what is required). The method I've used is to really use the `standalone` class, but to pass the 'required' class as an argument to that using a bit of trickery in the auxiliary compilation.

Note that some of this is a bit low-level (for example the box stuff) and some of that could be moved 'higher up'. Also note that at least restricted `\write18` is required, and that I've not added mutli-pass, BibTeX or similar support, but that this could be done with a bit of effort (probably using a keyval approach for the optional argument).

Comment: Probably the 'correct' solution is of course to ask for a feature to be added to `showexpl` to do this natively, using one or other of the available approaches.

Comment: Nice! Why doesn't it pick up `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`? I'm trying to write some Norwegian æøå letters...

Comment: @Holene `listings` isn't 'UTF-8 safe' as with an 8-bit engine characters are not always one byte. There are some questions on the site about this.