# listings using tcolorbox for beamer documentclass

Tags: beamer, listings, document-classes, tcolorbox, listingsutf8

I'm trying to get `listings` using `tcolorbox` for `beamer` `documentclass`. My MWE is given below but could not get it working. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

---

### MWE

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}%
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{ % General setup for the package
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    frame=tb,
    tabsize=4,
    columns=fixed,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    keepspaces,
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}%



\tcbset{listing engine={listings}}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

\blindtext

% Redefine the document environment within a group
\begingroup
\renewenvironment{document}{}{}
\renewcommand\documentclass[2][]{}

\begin{tcblisting}{colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!25,left=6mm,
listing options={style=tcblatex,numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny\color{red!75!black}}}
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{First Frame}
            \blindtext  
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Second Frame}
            \blindtext  
    \end{frame}

\end{document}

\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Listings for `beamer` documentclass. See between   `\begin{tcblisting} ... \end{tcblisting}`.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6006/how-to-use-showexpl-with-an-external-class

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The `tcblisting` environment does show the code listing as well it's output, but this can not work, when there is an additional `\documentclass` inside of the listing (as it is tried to setup/typeset this 'fake' document). For sure, if the documentclass is `relax`ed (well, expanding to nothing in this case), all beamer specific commands are unknown

Comment: @ChristianHupfer ah thanks, I'll delete comment (maybe I'll read the listings doc one day:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I think, this has nothing to do with `listings` package itself ... it's rather this special feature of the `tcblisting` environment from `tcolorbox` package, which causes this problem

Comment: @MYaseen208: I think, your request is not possible, as it would mean, that `tcblisting` should output beamer slides. You can show the code of course, but in this case, you would have to provide the output as graphics file as well.

Comment: Thanks @ChristianHupfer for your efforts. I would be happy with showing beamer code and include graphics file for slide.

Comment: @MYaseen208: I see, that Thomas F. Sturm basically has done, what I proposed to you

Comment: Yes @ChristianHupfer. Thanks for all people help and time here and especially yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would put the beamer example into a separate file which can be compiled for its own. Then, the source code and the beamer slides can be included into the target document.

Here, I used `example01.tex` for the beamer file:

```
% example01.tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{First Frame}
            \blindtext
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Second Frame}
            \blindtext
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

After compilation of this file, include the the result with `\tcbinputlisting`. The two slides are loaded within the `comment` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}%
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{ % General setup for the package
    language={[LaTeX]TeX},
    basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    frame=tb,
    tabsize=4,
    columns=fixed,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    keepspaces,
    commentstyle=\color{red},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}
}%



\tcbset{listing engine={listings}}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

\blindtext

\tcbinputlisting{listing file=example01.tex,
listing and comment,
comment={\includegraphics[width=\the\dimexpr 0.5\linewidth-1mm\relax,page=1]{example01}\hfill%
  \includegraphics[width=\the\dimexpr 0.5\linewidth-1mm\relax,page=2]{example01}},
colback=red!5!white,colframe=red!25,left=6mm,
leftlower=0pt,rightlower=0pt,
listing options={style=tcblatex,numbers=left,numberstyle=\tiny\color{red!75!black}}}

\end{document}
```

This gives:

> [image]

Comment: (+1) Thanks Prof. Dr. Thomas F. Sturm for your nice answer and help. Especially for such a wonderful package.

Comment: Please also guide me read external file in `\texexptitled` environment.