# Beamer: How to showcase LaTeX-Code and results that look like scrartcl

Tags: beamer, listings, koma-script, tcolorbox

We are currently working on a beginner's course for LaTeX.

We are using LuaLaTeX and Beamer for the slides. 
We typeset code with the `listings`-package.

We often show Code on the left and a result on the right. For most parts adding a `\rmfamily` is enough to let it look like the result one would get in an `article`-class and not in beamer.

But not so for `\item`, `\ref`, `\caption` and some other features.

My dream would be an environment `scrartcl-result`.

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe you could provide a MWE showing what works and what doesn't with your current approach?

Comment: I will add this during this week. What works is: We have Roman Font for text. Nothing else. The `itemize`-points look like beamer, the equation-numbers are sans-serif ...

Comment: Related: [How to use Showexpl with an external class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6006/how-to-use-showexpl-with-an-external-class)

Comment: I know this answer. Is there no way that does not  involve creating and loading several dozens of pdfs?

Comment: @MaxNoe [Joseph Wright's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/128677/1952) creates and loads all pdfs on the fly, you don't have to do it by yourself. Is not enough?

Comment: From the top of my head i would have suggested the same approach given by @Joseph in the linked answer. If you want something to look like `scrartcl` use it. beamer uses a whole lot of different mechanisms to do beamer stuff. Reinventing the wheel seems to be much more effort than necessary.

Comment: If you are worried about compile time, use a simple switch to compile with `pdflatex` most of the time. You can test if the pdf that would be generated is already there, so it can be used directly. But add a switch that forces compilation anyway, in case your code changes. You might also want to check the TikZ externnalization library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We now have an environment (with `xparse`, but not necessary) that lets everything we need to look like `article`. Hardest part were the equation numbers because of the lacking `beamer` font template.

You have to use `~` for the white space in the `beamer` template names.

```
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentEnvironment {EmulateArticle} {} {
  %Roman Font:
  \rmfamily

  %Itemize/Enumerate/Description
  \setbeamercolor{item}{fg=black}
  \setbeamerfont{item}{family=\rmfamily, size=\normalsize}
  \setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate~body}{family=\rmfamily}
  \setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate~subbody}{family=\rmfamily}
  \setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate~subsubbody}{family=\rmfamily}
  \setbeamerfont{description~item}{series=\bfseries}
  \setbeamertemplate{itemize~item}{\bullet}
  \setbeamertemplate{itemize~subitem}{--}
  \setbeamertemplate{itemize~subsubitem}{\textasteriskcentered}
  \setbeamertemplate{enumerate~item}{\theenumi.}
  \setbeamertemplate{enumerate~subitem}{\alph{enumii})}
  \setbeamertemplate{enumerate~subsubitem}{\roman{enumii}.}

  % Captions
  \setbeamerfont{caption}{family=\rmfamily}
  \setbeamercolor{caption~name}{fg=black}
  \setbeamerfont{caption~name}{family=\rmfamily, series=\bfseries}

  % Footnotes
  \setbeamerfont{footnote}{family=\rmfamily}
  \setbeamerfont{footnote~mark}{family=\rmfamily}


  % Serif Equation Numbers:
  \let\reftagform@=\tagform@
  \def\tagform@##1{\maketag@@@{(\ignorespaces{\rmfamily{##1}}\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}
  \renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\reftagform@{\rmfamily\ref{##1}}}}
}{
}
\makeatother
```

The Slides are available at  http://toolbox.pep-dortmund.org/files/archive/latest/latex.pdf

Our Github-Repo is https://github.com/pep-dortmund/toolbox-workshop

One might want to add settings for the bibliography-output.