# Article example inside beamer frame

Tags: beamer, minipage

Let us assume that we have the following example code for an article

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Sample title}
\author{Sample author}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Sample section}
\end{document}
```

I wish to include the **output** of the above code as a `minipage` in my beamer frame. How can I do that?  I would prefer a vector output rather than a PNG / JPG screenshot.

Comment: Compile to PDF. `\usepackage{pdfpages}` and `\includepdf{filename}`?

Answer (score 7):

The easiest would be to create a separate document that contains the article content and include it as an image. Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\Tiny\tiny% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94159/5764
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}

\begin{SaveVerbatim}{CodeBox}
\documentclass{article}
\title{Sample title}
\author{Sample author}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Sample section}
\end{document}
\end{SaveVerbatim}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{\LaTeX{} code}

  \begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
    \UseVerbatim{CodeBox}
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{article}%
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

If you want to include a specific page from `article.pdf`, use the key-value `page=<num>` to include page `<num>` from `article.pdf`. You could also frame the page by using instead

```
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule]{article}}
```

Note that code is stored in a box using [`fancyvrb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) and recalled inside the `frame`. Since you're dealing with [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) containing verbatim-like content, set the `frame` properties to `[fragile]`.

Comment: What's the purpose adda % at below line:\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{article}%. I see such code many times but don't know the reason!

Comment: @Beatlej: It's not necessary here (perhaps just used in habit). See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)

Answer (score 6):

Creating a separate document for the article is the easiest way. It has to be compiled only once and output plus source code can be included in the beamer frame.

But if you prefer to have only one source document which starts the compilation of the article, you can use the following (based on `tcolorbox`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[skins,listings,raster]{tcolorbox}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{\LaTeX{} code}

\begin{tcblisting}{
  enhanced,oversize,lower separated=false,
  colframe=red!50!black,colback=yellow!10!white,
  interior style={top color=yellow!5!white,bottom color=yellow!20!white},
  listing side comment,
  listing options={style=tcblatex,texcsstyle=*\color{red!70!black}},
  pdf comment,
  comment style={drop lifted shadow},
  compilable listing,
  run pdflatex,
  raster columns=1}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Sample title}
\author{Sample author}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Sample section}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
\end{tcblisting}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Since the compilation of the article has to be started during compilation of the beamer frames, you have to use the `-shell-escape` option.

> ```
> pdflatex -shell-escape mybeamerfile.tex
> ```

The example contains just one page. To select e.g. a possible page 3, you could use

```
comment style={drop lifted shadow,graphics pages={3}}
```

You can also show more than one page of output, but the size of each will shrink:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[skins,listings,raster]{tcolorbox}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{\LaTeX{} code}

\begin{tcblisting}{
  enhanced,oversize,lower separated=false,
  colframe=red!50!black,colback=yellow!10!white,
  interior style={top color=yellow!5!white,bottom color=yellow!20!white},
  listing side comment,sidebyside gap=5mm,
  listing options={style=tcblatex,texcsstyle=*\color{red!70!black}},
  pdf comment,
  comment style={drop small lifted shadow},
  compilable listing,
  run pdflatex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,tikz}
\title{Sample title}
\author{Sample author}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Sample section}
\lipsum[1-12]
\begin{center}
\tikz\shadedraw [shading=ball]
  (0,0) circle (3cm);
\end{center}
\end{document}
\end{tcblisting}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```