# Recreate Word document to include inside .tex

Tags: minipage, msword, parbox, word-to-latex

I would like to include 3 pages of a word document (an Informed Consent for my studies) in my .tex document.

I could include each PDF but I would like to know **how can I recreate the document in TeX and include it (reducing a bit the size) with some caption?** `Minipage`?

(Using Overleaf and PDFLaTeX)

Here is an example of one page I want to recreate:

[image]

Here is my MWE (with some warnings):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %for a header
\usepackage{amssymb} %for the $\Box$
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand*{\SignatureAndDate}[1]{%
    \par\noindent\makebox[5cm]{\hrulefill} \hfill\makebox[4cm]{\hrulefill}%
    \par\noindent\makebox[5cm][l]{#1}      \hfill\makebox[4cm][l]{Date}%
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{PROJECT name: here goes the title for the project that is in the header\\ Participant Information on the study}

\begin{document}
\section*{Introduction}
You have been invited to participate in a study of the Faculty xx of the University of yy in 
the  scope  of  the  zz  project.  This  information  sheet  describes  the  study  and  your 
participation in it. The researcher will answer any question or doubt regarding this study. 

\noindent Your participation is voluntary, and you are free to decide not to enrol or abandon your 
participation at any moment without prejudice of any relation with the project or your 
institution.

\noindent Please  carefully  read  this  information  sheet  before  signing  the  following  informed 
consent. 

\section*{Aim of the study}
The goal of this study is to...


{\centering \section*{Informed Consent}}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}p{12cm}p{3cm}@{}}
I declare that I have read the information above and that I understood the aim of 
the study, as well as the risks and benefits of my participation in the study.& $\Box$\\[5ex]
I had the time and opportunity to place all the questions I had about the study and 
the experimental protocol and all my questions were answered.& $\Box$\\[5ex]
All the information, oral or written, and discussion about the study were provided 
to me either in English or in another language in which I am also proficient.& $\Box$\\[5ex]
I was informed that my participation in this study is voluntary and the refusal to 
participate will not involve any punitive action of any sort.& $\Box$\\[5ex]
I  was  informed  that  all  the  information  collected  during  this  study  would  be 
treated with confidentiality.& $\Box$\\[5ex]
Finally, I declare that I participate willingly in this study.& $\Box$
\end{tabular}

\vspace{2cm}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{ll}
\makebox[7cm]{\hrulefill} &\\
Participant’s name &\\[5ex]
\makebox[7cm]{\hrulefill} & \makebox[3cm]{\hrulefill}\\
Participant’s signature & Date\\[5ex]
\makebox[7cm]{\hrulefill} & \makebox[3cm]{\hrulefill}\\
Researcher’s signature & Date\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to recreate the document in TeX or asking how to include them with some sort of caption? If you don't mind reducing them in size slightly, then including them with a caption would be the simplest solution. Alternatively, if you want them to be included as regular pages in the thesis, you can add the proper page numbering etc.   But at the moment I'm not quite sure what the question is.

Comment: @AlanMunn Recreating the document in TeX and include it (reducing a bit the size) with some caption.

Comment: Save the Word as a pdf and then include the pdf with `pdfpages` package.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I know that (read my post before the bold lines), but I would like to know how to recreate it in TeX and then include it with some caption in a document.

Comment: Do you want to include a page in a minipage? The same page, even? "Document" means (1) the typeset version (=PDF); or (2) the Latex code instructions. When you say "recreate" document and "include" it in another, do you mean recreate (1) and include (2); recreate (2) and include (1); recreate (1) and include (1)? A minipage can display the page it is on (including itself) if there is a two-pass, not in a single run (the output cannot include itself at the same time, because it is not yet finished). So, the answer seems to be: use two codes: one for PDF (recreate) and one for include.

Comment: Tikz can *emulate* a page, and it has a scale option.

Comment: @Cicada I will try to clarify: I have my .tex document (**myTEX.tex**) where I want to insert another document (**otherTEX.tex**) as a _"figure"_ that has some caption. This **otherTEX.tex** is my attempt to recreate the Word document above (not very successful at it). So, can you help recreate **otherTEX.tex** and then include it in **myTEX.tex** with some caption?

Comment: One `\documentclass` per document.

Comment: See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222475/article-example-inside-beamer-frame/222498#222498  It always comes back to: the document/figure to be inserted is the typeset document (=PDF) even if the typeset document to insert was produced during the compilation run of the including document (using shell-escape).

Comment: The structure could be simply a minipage with a` \fbox` in a float:  `(figure(fbox(minipage(content))) (caption))` (obviously this is not code, but a scheme of what is inside what) where "content" could be the fake Word text  with a generous  `\fboxsep` (to simulate margins) and a smaller font,  or if you want to preserve headers, footers, title, etc.  that cannot be generated "as is" inside the minipage, make the "content" in PDF (i.e., `pdflatex MWE.tex`) and include the PDF as an image (i.e. `\includegraphics[page=1, width=\linewidth]{MWE}`) .

Answer (score 2):

`tcolorbox` package example, from: [article inside beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222475/article-example-inside-beamer-frame)

[image: included PDF shell escape]

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[skins,listings,raster]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tcblisting}{
  enhanced,oversize,lower separated=false,
  colframe=red!50!black,colback=yellow!10!white,
  interior style={top color=yellow!5!white,bottom color=yellow!20!white},
%  listing side comment,
  comment only,
  listing options={style=tcblatex,texcsstyle=*\color{red!70!black}},
  pdf comment,
  comment style={drop lifted shadow},
  compilable listing,
  run xelatex,
  raster columns=1}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{blue!1}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %for a header
\usepackage{amssymb} %for the $\Box$
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\headheight}{30pt}
\newcommand*{\SignatureAndDate}[1]{%
    \par\noindent\makebox[5cm]{\hrulefill} \hfill\makebox[4cm]{\hrulefill}%
    \par\noindent\makebox[5cm][l]{#1}      \hfill\makebox[4cm][l]{Date}%
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{PROJECT name: here goes the title for the project that is in the header\\ Participant Information on the study}

\begin{document}
\section*{Introduction}
You have been invited to participate in a study of the Faculty xx of the University of yy in 
the  scope  of  the  zz  project.  This  information  sheet  describes  the  study  and  your 
participation in it. The researcher will answer any question or doubt regarding this study. 

\noindent Your participation is voluntary, and you are free to decide not to enrol or abandon your 
participation at any moment without prejudice of any relation with the project or your 
institution.

\noindent Please  carefully  read  this  information  sheet  before  signing  the  following  informed 
consent. 

\section*{Aim of the study}
The goal of this study is to...


{\centering \section*{Informed Consent}}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}p{12cm}p{3cm}@{}}
I declare that I have read the information above and that I understood the aim of 
the study, as well as the risks and benefits of my participation in the study.& $\Box$\\[5ex]
I had the time and opportunity to place all the questions I had about the study and 
the experimental protocol and all my questions were answered.& $\Box$\\[5ex]
All the information, oral or written, and discussion about the study were provided 
to me either in English or in another language in which I am also proficient.& $\Box$\\[5ex]
I was informed that my participation in this study is voluntary and the refusal to 
participate will not involve any punitive action of any sort.& $\Box$\\[5ex]
I  was  informed  that  all  the  information  collected  during  this  study  would  be 
treated with confidentiality.& $\Box$\\[5ex]
Finally, I declare that I participate willingly in this study.& $\Box$
\end{tabular}

\vspace{2cm}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{ll}
\makebox[7cm]{\hrulefill} &\\
Participant’s name &\\[5ex]
\makebox[7cm]{\hrulefill} & \makebox[3cm]{\hrulefill}\\
Participant’s signature & Date\\[5ex]
\makebox[7cm]{\hrulefill} & \makebox[3cm]{\hrulefill}\\
Researcher’s signature & Date\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
\end{tcblisting}
\caption{The Consent Form}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

Original suggestion:

Try some experiments with `latexdemo` package.

[image: page 1]

[image: page 2]

[image: page 3]

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagecolor{blue!2}
\usepackage{latexdemo}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} %for a header
\usepackage{amssymb} %for the $\Box$
\usepackage{tabularx}
\setlength{\headheight}{30pt}
\newcommand*{\SignatureAndDate}[1]{%
    \par\noindent\makebox[5cm]{\hrulefill} \hfill\makebox[4cm]{\hrulefill}%
    \par\noindent\makebox[5cm][l]{#1}      \hfill\makebox[4cm][l]{Date}%
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\chead{PROJECT name: here goes the title for the project that is in the header\\ Participant Information on the study}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite,nosearch,noheader]{\democodefile}
\section*{Introduction}
You have been invited to participate in a study of the Faculty xx of the University of yy in 
the  scope  of  the  zz  project.  This  information  sheet  describes  the  study  and  your 
participation in it. The researcher will answer any question or doubt regarding this study. 

\noindent Your participation is voluntary, and you are free to decide not to enrol or abandon your 
participation at any moment without prejudice of any relation with the project or your 
institution.

\noindent Please  carefully  read  this  information  sheet  before  signing  the  following  informed 
consent. 

\section*{Aim of the study}
The goal of this study is to...

%\begin{figure}
\fbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{formshrink_read}}
%\caption{The Consent Form}
%\end{figure}

{\centering \section*{Informed Consent}}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}p{12cm}p{3cm}@{}}
I declare that I have read the information above and that I understood the aim of 
the study, as well as the risks and benefits of my participation in the study.& $\Box$\\[5ex]
I had the time and opportunity to place all the questions I had about the study and 
the experimental protocol and all my questions were answered.& $\Box$\\[5ex]
All the information, oral or written, and discussion about the study were provided 
to me either in English or in another language in which I am also proficient.& $\Box$\\[5ex]
I was informed that my participation in this study is voluntary and the refusal to 
participate will not involve any punitive action of any sort.& $\Box$\\[5ex]
I  was  informed  that  all  the  information  collected  during  this  study  would  be 
treated with confidentiality.& $\Box$\\[5ex]
Finally, I declare that I participate willingly in this study.& $\Box$
\end{tabular}

\vspace{2cm}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{ll}
\makebox[7cm]{\hrulefill} &\\
Participant’s name &\\[5ex]
\makebox[7cm]{\hrulefill} & \makebox[3cm]{\hrulefill}\\
Participant’s signature & Date\\[5ex]
\makebox[7cm]{\hrulefill} & \makebox[3cm]{\hrulefill}\\
Researcher’s signature & Date\\
\end{tabular}\end{filecontents}
\PrintDemo {style=stacked}


\end{document}
```