# nesting documentclasses

Tags: beamer, pdftex, document-classes

I'm creating (beamer) slides explaining the basics of using LaTeX. For this purpose I would like to illustrate how some source code

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{My first paper}
\begin{document}
...
```

looks like. That is, I'd like to compile some LaTeX code using the article document class and display it on my slide (without manually compiling a separate document and then including the produced pdf). What's the best/easiest way of achieving this?

At first look the `showexpl` package or similar look like they might work, but it breaks beamer when including things like `\section` in the sample code, and things like `\title` display beamer-style.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Side-by-side source and output when documenting a style file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19295/5764); [Any way to show LaTeX example code *and* execute it?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110349/5764)

Comment: I think `tcolorbox` has such a functionality.

Comment: @Werner Thanks for the link, certainly related but not exactly what I was looking for - rather than combining the source code and compiled display into on environment which prevents me from skipping some lines for brevity, I'd like to be able to just display the compiled result by itself.

Comment: @samcarter Thanks, tcolorbox does seem to support this via tcblisting. However, I'm struggling to get a working example, as even the supplied tcolorbox-example.tex fails to compile, with `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/sharp corners'` and a bunch of similar errors.

Comment: @Henning Koehler: You need the `enhanced` option as well

Comment: You could always use the `pdfpages` package to include output from a separate document, compiled under a different document class.

Comment: @Steven I could, but then I'd need to keep a separate document for each example. That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Understood, though you wouldn't need a separate document for each example...only a separate document for each document class.

Comment: I think this question was already done: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6006/how-to-use-showexpl-with-an-external-class and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222498/1952

Comment: Also similar here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279068/how-to-display-latex-code-and-the-typeset-version-next-to-each-other-without-rep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tcolorbox` is a nice way to show source code and its output along site. Now your question is about showing the output without the source as you want to "skipping some lines for brevity".

My suggestion would be to use `firstline=24, lastline=42` to select the lines, that you want to show, but if you insist to not show the source:

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{
          listing options={%
            style=tcblatex,
            firstline=0,
            lastline=0
          },
          listing and comment,
          pdf comment,
          compilable listing,
          run pdflatex,
          lower separated=false,
          top=-\baselineskip
        }

\documentclass{article}
\title{Theory of Everything}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I want - however I still can't get it to compile (`! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/pdf comment ...`). Must be something with my latex setup, but no idea what (using pdflatex).

Comment: @HenningKoehler `pdflatex` is fine, I used it for the above example, too. Which tex distribution do you have? Which version of `tcolorbox`?

Comment: The answers to that would be `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)` and `Package: tcolorbox 2014/02/06 version 2.70 text color boxes`. Essentially the defaults for Ubuntu 14.04. (which I'm not planning to upgrade anytime soon).

Comment: @HenningKoehler https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu